# Kafka Teradata Source Connector fetching Column Title

Tags: apache-kafka, teradata, apache-kafka-connect

Using Kafka Confluent Teradata source connector to read data from a table into a Kafka topic. This is working as expected as long as the Teradata table doesn't contain Column Title. If Column Title is present, it's referring the **Column Title** instead of **Column name** and getting the error. In the error message Emp ID is the Column Title and EMP_ID is the column name.

```
Error:
Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: Emp ID
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.validateName(Schema.java:1532)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema.access$400(Schema.java:87)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:520)
        at org.apache.avro.Schema$Field.<init>(Schema.java:559)
```

Tried multiple options and came up with the following workaround of giving query in property files, this is working as expected. But the problem is we have 100's of tables to pull from Teradata, with this workaround we need to create separate property file for each table and have to mention all the columns explicitly. This makes complicated from maintenance perspective.

```
query=SELECT EMP_ID AS EMP_ID, CRET_TS AS CRET_TS FROM schema.table
```

Hoping someone could help over this.

Comment: Are you referring to the JDBC Source connector? Or a different connector?

Comment: Using Teradata Connector  https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-teradata/source-connector/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Append the COLUMN_NAME=ON option to the Teradata URL

```
jdbc:teradata://mytdname/COLUMN_NAME=ON,
```